# SQL Dynamic SUM of column values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this sql but what I was looking to do was to have another column which had the total of the other matches column like this...

[image]

```
declare @SchoolID int
declare @RoleID int
declare @match int
declare @firstname varchar

set @SchoolID=1
set @RoleID=1

SELECT     
    dbo.Teacher.Firstname, 
    dbo.School.SchoolName, 
    dbo.School.SchoolID, 
    dbo.RoleTitle.RoleTitle,
    CASE WHEN dbo.School.SchoolID = @SchoolID then 1 else 0 end as [SchoolMatch],
    CASE WHEN dbo.JobTitle.RoleTitleID = @RoleID then 1 else 0 end as [RoleMatch]

FROM         
    dbo.School INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lesson ON dbo.School.SchoolID = dbo.Lesson.SchoolID INNER JOIN
    dbo.RoleTitle ON dbo.Lesson.RoleTitleID = dbo.RoleTitle.RoleTitleID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Teacher ON dbo.Lesson.TeacherID = dbo.Teacher.TeacherID
```

Comment: @bluefeet The OP did show desired results (see the screenshot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just repeat your case statements and add them.

```
SELECT
  .
  .
CASE WHEN dbo.School.SchoolID = @SchoolID then 1 else 0 end +
  CASE WHEN dbo.JobTitle.RoleTitleID = @RoleID then 1 else 0 end as [NewColumn]
```

Comment: thanks for that. Is there also a way of totalling the columns. Would I need a union for this?

Comment: @okenshield -  You mean like one extra row at the end with the sum of all rows? You could solve that with a duplicate query in a `union` or perhaps you could use [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). I have never used it so I couldn't tell you how it should be done in your case. I guess that I would probably sum it up in the client code somewhere and not bothering SQL Server with that. Depends on where you are going to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Teacher.Firstname, 
    dbo.School.SchoolName, 
    dbo.School.SchoolID, 
    dbo.RoleTitle.RoleTitle,
    CASE WHEN dbo.School.SchoolID = @SchoolID then 1 else 0 end as [SchoolMatch],
    CASE WHEN dbo.JobTitle.RoleTitleID = @RoleID then 1 else 0 end as [RoleMatch],
    (CASE WHEN dbo.School.SchoolID = @SchoolID then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE WHEN dbo.JobTitle.RoleTitleID = @RoleID then 1 else 0 end) AS NewColumn
FROM         
    dbo.School INNER JOIN
    dbo.Lesson ON dbo.School.SchoolID = dbo.Lesson.SchoolID INNER JOIN
    dbo.RoleTitle ON dbo.Lesson.RoleTitleID = dbo.RoleTitle.RoleTitleID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Teacher ON dbo.Lesson.TeacherID = dbo.Teacher.TeacherID
```

Comment: It's SQL Server, it does support CTEs.

Comment: Did not see that. Updated the answer.